**SOLVED** New to Linux. Started with no monitor recognized, now have correct resolution but everything is RED
I'm literally brand new to Linux. Day 1 today. Having a bit of a rough go with it, already worked through some issues, but this one is really slowing me down.
Elementary seems to be getting zero information from my monitor regarding what it's capable of. It's defaulting to 1024x768, it's a 2560x1440 monitor LG 32GP-850-B running over DisplayPort. Runs at 180hz, but I'd be fine if I can get it to run at 144hz....or at least mildly happy with just the correct resolution. At least then I could stop using Windows for everything but games.
I've tried installing NVIDIA drivers via the AppCenter, also tried downloading them from NVIDIA's site, but the file just opens "Code" instead of any kind of installer like I'd normally expect as a lifetime Windows user. Code proceeds to do nothing.
Looking around, I've tried to use xrandr to get some information but it just reports the one mode for the default and that's it. It also lists the display device as "None-1". I'm honestly not sure if this is a NVIDIA driver issue, or specific to my monitor. I'm having to bounce back and forth between Windows and Linux to troubleshoot, because honestly everything is completely unreadable at that low resolution. It's like trying to read a book with 200 point fonts. :P
Other info that may or may not be relevant:
AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
32 GB RAM
EVGA RTX3080 FTW3
LG 32GP850-B monitor
Elementary OS 7.1 Horus
I'll get the actual output from xrandr and update this post. Thank you in advance for any tips or suggestions. Really looking forward to getting things up and running and expanding my knowledge base.
--edit--
None-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      60.00*+
That's the output xrandr gives me. I also installed inxi and am seeing the following:
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080] driver: N/A
  Device-2: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nouveau unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: N/A
    resolution: 1024x768~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
    v: 4.5 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2

If I'm understanding that correctly, it appears the NVIDIA driver did not actually install?
--edit 2--
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

This gets me to the correct resolution, and then it's seeing EDID info apparently, as it shows LG Electronics 31" in Displays....but everything is now red.
Trying to reinstall drivers from app center returns to normal colors..but then it doesn't see the monitor again, and only 1024x768.
I have also tried: purge, then
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-550

This returns the following, note the errors that says dependency problems etc....
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-550 is already the newest version (550.120-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up nvidia-dkms-550 (550.120-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Removing old nvidia-550.120 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-550.120 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-550.120 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-49-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-49-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/550.120/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-550 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-550 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-550:
 nvidia-driver-550 depends on nvidia-dkms-550 (<= 550.120-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-550 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-550 depends on nvidia-dkms-550 (>= 550.120); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-550 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-550 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-49-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-550
 nvidia-driver-550


try purging nvidia again, reboot and then try with 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'

My hero! It would seem this has worked. Colors are normal, and "cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version"  is showing the right one now. Thank you so much!
